# Python search / extract string before and after a character

Tags: python, regex

Need help in extracting string before and after a character using regex in python

```
string = "My City | August 5"
```

I would like to extract `"My City"` and extract `"August 5"`

```
string1 = "My City"
string2 = "August 5"
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a regex here, just use [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition), splitting on the `|` plus the surrounding spaces:

```
string1, separator, string2 = string.partition(' | ')
```

Demo:

```
>>> string = "My City | August 5"
>>> string.partition(' | ')
('My City', ' | ', 'August 5')
>>> string1, separator, string2 = string.partition(' | ')
>>> string1
'My City'
>>> string2
'August 5'
```

`str.partition()` splits the string *just once*; if there are more `|` characters those are left as part of `string2`.

If you want to make it a little more robust and handle any number of spaces around the pipe symbol, you can split on *just* `|` and use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove arbitrary amounts of whitespace from the start and end of the two strings:

```
string1, separator, string2 = map(str.strip, string.partition('|'))
```

Comment: I like the use of partition, it handles the case where the `'|'` is not present.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regular expressions here. Just type

```
string = "My City | August 5"
string1, string2 = string.split("|")
```

If you want to crop the trailing space in the results, you can use

```
string1 = string1.strip(" ")
string2 = string2.strip(" ")
```

Comment: You should use `.split("|", 1)`

Comment: Why should I? I don't see a hint that the string should be split only at the first occurence. Actually, as there's only one pipe character in the given example, it doesn't matter at all...

Comment: The examples says "before and after" but yes it's unclear in the question so maybe not

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here's a built in method for splitting a string:

```
string = "My City | August 5"
delimiter = ' | '  # note the spaces are part of your delimiter
list_of_partial_strings = string.split(delimiter)
```

There's excellent documentation available for string methods in the [Python Standard Library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 1):

Through regex, it would be like

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "My City | August 5"
>>> string1, string2 = re.split(r'\s+\|\s+', string)
>>> string1
'My City'
>>> string2
'August 5'
```

`\s+` matches one or more space characters, `\|` matches a literal `|` symbol . You must need to escape the `|` in your regex to match a literal `|` symbol because `|` pipe is a special meta character in regex which was usually called as alternation operator or logical OR operator.